# Enemy ranged vs melee units

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I am having a difficult time seeing what enemy units are ranged units (aside from graphical cues). Is there a marker in the enemy info sheet that shows that units have a ranged attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the range icon in the enemy stats.

If it says "Half" or "Full", the unit is ranged.

Melee units, by contrast, have a listed range of "None".

[image]